# MarkLogic SSL Certificate Generation/Use

Tags: marklogic

We are trying to set up an SSL cert in marklogic. When using the ML admin GUI to generate a certificate, we cannot see any way to set the "common name" we need for the certificate.

What is the best way to handle this? Do we need to create the certificate elsewhere and import it into marklogic? If so, what is the best way to import it? After importing do we then use xquery to apply it against a particular app server

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the guide here:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/SSL

You see no common name because you are initially just setting up a template to use in MarkLogic. Common names are part of the hostname and are in a later step.  High level steps you will see in the guide:

1. Create a Template
2. Navigate to an app server
3. Set the ssl template and ssl hostname
4. Back to the ssl configuration, go to the template and download the certificate  request.
5. Once signed, re-import.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a pre-signed certificate and key for MarkLogic

hope this could help

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/297/0/import-pre-signed-certificate-and-key-for-marklogic-https-app-server

Comment: Try to write actual instruction instead of pasting a link. The link can be unreachable in the future.